# next.js "you may need an appropriate loader"

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, create-react-app, next.js

I am in the process of migrating the CRA-part (create-react-app) of an existing `CRA  + express.js` project to `next.js`. Currently, I only want to use next.js to generate my static pages. My folder structure looks like this:

```
|-client (CRA App)
|-server (express.js)
|-next-ssg (next.js)
```

I tried copying the navigation component from my main project (with some minor changes) but am now encountering the following error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
[ event ] build page: /next/dist/pages/_error
[ wait ]  compiling ...
[ error ] ./data/icons/amazon.png 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/.next/server/static/development/pages/_document'
Require stack:
- /Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/load-components.js
- /Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js
- /Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js
- /Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js
- /Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
- /Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js
- /Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:835:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1012:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.loadComponents (/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/load-components.js:24:25)
    at DevServer.findPageComponents (/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:555:60)
    at DevServer.renderErrorToHTML (/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:852:33)
    at DevServer.renderErrorToHTML (/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-dev-server.js:19:915)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async DevServer.render (/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:540:22)
    at async Object.fn (/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:390:17)
    at async Router.execute (/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/router.js:134:32)
    at async DevServer.run (/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:505:29)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:149:20) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/load-components.js',
    '/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js',
    '/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js',
    '/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js',
    '/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js',
    '/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js',
    '/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>/next-ssg/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'
  ]
}
```

## Update due to questions in the comments:

The images are located in the specified subfolder:

[image: publictree]

However, and that seems to be a problem, the initial import was done as it is typically done in create-react-app:

```
import AmazonIcon from "./icons/amazon.png";
<OMITTED FOR BREVITY>

const providerData = [
    {
        img: AmazonIcon,
        name: "amazon",
        href: "auth/amazon",
        alt: "amazon-icon",
        color: "#F9AE31",
        txt: "Login with Amazon"
    }
    <OMITTED FOR BREVITY>
];

export default providerData;
```

even after changing the `img`-key to `'public/data/icons/amazon.png'` I did not get it working.

```
Modal.js:170 GET http://localhost:3030/public/data/icons/amazon.png 404 (Not Found)
```

I reference the image like this:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const ImageDiv = styled("div")`
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 48px;
    background: url("${props => props.img}") no-repeat center center / 50% ${props => props.color}
`;

const img = (img, color) => {
   return <ImageDiv img={`../${img}`} color={color} />
}
```

Comment: Do you have a webpack.config.js file? If yes, can you post it please?

Comment: Nope, at least, not that I am aware of. Using create-next-app defaults.

Comment: You’re trying to import a `png` image without the appropriate webpack loader.

Comment: Did you put `amazon.png` in the the `public` folder of your `next` project (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)? Are you trying to `import` the image file as you would in CRA? Can you instead just reference the path to the file instead of trying to import it, in relation to the `public` folder? As in `<img src="/path/to/amazon.png"` instead of `<img src={importedImg}`.

Comment: Can you share some of the code for this component causing this error?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I did update the question. I hope that helps.

Comment: @BertrandMarron yes, it would appear that way, I am not familiar with webpack, babel and the likes. I've been trying to read up on them, but have not yet found a good starting point. Pointers appreciated

Comment: This is a pretty good starting point: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/

Comment: Don't import `AmazonIcon`  instead put icon inside icons folder in public folder on project's root  and give path to that in `img:"/data/icons/amazon.png"`   You don't need to specify public in path name